# Looking up a specific widget by its id in the Dojo Toolkit

Tags: dojo

I am developing a mobile application with the Dojo Toolkit. I have the following widget:

```
define("js/custom/CustomHeading", [ "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/dom-class", "dojox/mobile/Heading", "dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton",
    "dojo/ready" ], function(declare, domConstruct, domClass, Heading,
    ToolBarButton, ready) {

return declare("js.custom.CustomHeading", [ Heading ], {

    buildRendering : function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        navigationButton = new dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton({
            icon : "js/custom/images/navigation.png"
        });

        navigationButton.placeAt(this.domNode);

        ready(function() {
            console.log("I entered the block.");
        });

    }
});
```

});

If I try to find a widget that is in my html using `dijit.byId()`, I get no successful result. Dojo can not find the widget, whereas it is there. The widget I want to find looks as follows:

```
<div id="navigationOverlay" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Overlay">
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="moveTo:'dataServerRuntime',transition:'slide',label:'Health Summary'"
            onclick="hideNavigation();"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I find the widget?

Comment: Perhaps it is a timing issue - have you checked the code is running after the HTML is [parsed](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html) for dijits?

Comment: In my `data-dojo-config` attribute I use `parseOnLoad: true`. Wouldn't that solve the timing issue? If not, how I prevent my code from running before the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dojo/ready`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/ready):

```
ready(function() {
    var navigationWidget = reqistry.byId("navigationOverlay"); 
})
```

An example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/tgU2x/

Comment: This works, but I can not use it in my declare block, I do not know why. If I write `var navigationWidget = registry.byId("navigationOverlay");` in the `ready(function() {})` function, the block is not entered. Outside of the declare block it works fine.

Comment: How do you know the block is not entered? Did you try `console.log()` or `alert()` from the block? Maybe you have something more inside the block and you need to execute the block in the correct score, i.e. when `this` points to the widget, try: `ready(this, function() { /*...*/ })` or use closure.

Comment: Yes, I tried `console.log()`. I updated the listing above to show you what I have now.

Comment: Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/tgU2x/), it works fine there.

Comment: It works in another widget but not in `js.widget.CustomHeading`. In my log I see this line `Uncaught Error: Tried to register widget with id==js_custom_CustomHeading_0 but that id is already registered`. I think this error is the cause. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Your `js.widget.CustomHeading` instance gets auto-generated `id` of `js_custom_CustomHeading_0` when you do not provide `id` explicitly. You cannot create two widgets with the same `id`, but somehow you are trying to. I do not know how, because if you create another `js.widget.CustomHeading` instance without `id` specified, it should get `id` of `js_custom_CustomHeading_1` and so on.

Comment: I set the `id` explicitly now, but I get the same error for all of my views now. My views have unique id and are implemented declaratively. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I just use this widget once, so how can this conflict occur?

Comment: Do not know how your code looks like. Try to use [Dojo Firebug Extension](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DojoFirebugExtension_Reference_Guide) to explore widgets on a page. Or open another question as this one is solved and maybe it is some specific `dojox/mobile` problem, someone else can help you with. I created 4 instances of `dojox/mobile/Heading` subclassed widget at the aforementioned jsFiddle and it works as expected. The problem must be somewhere else.